# Microsoft Access Linking fields from another table

Tags: sql, forms, ms-access, field

I'm trying to create an invoice table, and ultimately a form that automatically gets data from a different table called Photo. The Photo table has a field called "salesprice" and the invoice table has field called "Cost". The tables are joined by a primary key of PhotoID which is already linked in a combobox field.

The goal is to select the appropriate PhotoID and then the salesprice auto-populates into the Cost field. Currently the "Cost" row is a combobox with row source being:

```
SELECT [Photo].[ID], [Photo].[SalePrice] FROM Photo;
```

The field now has a drop down list with all the available costs, but I want it only to have the cost associated with the row's photo ID.

[image: This is what the Invoice's table currently looks like]

.
[image: The ultimate goal is to make the form below update the cost field when you change the photoid]

I'm a bit new to access, but have tried a few things and cannot get it to work. Because I was implementing this into a subform I thought it would be best to do it at the table level unless someone has a better approach? Ant help would be great thanks!

Comment: SELECT [Photo].[ID], [Photo].[SalePrice] FROM Photo; 

Currently a drop down menu appears with all the available SalesPrices from all the photos, but I want the price to be only the one that corresponds to the row's photoId

Comment: Is seems your `Cost` field is a lookup field.  As a quick test, export the table to Excel.  Then when you open the worksheet, are the values in the `Cost` column what you expect? Are they actually `[ID]` values instead of `[SalePrice]` values?

Answer (score 0):

This is a different direction than you are heading, but could achieve what you're attempting to build.

To maintain database normalization, you generally don't want to store a field in multiple tables because it wastes resources by storing the same information in two places. Trying to link data in one table to another can be accomplished with a simple query used as the datasource of your subform (instead of using a table).

Copy the following code into the SQL view of a new query and overwrite the form control reference `[MyInvoiceFormName]![MyInvoiceTextboxName]` to match the name of your form and invoice ID textbox. Check to make sure it's pulling the data you want by running it (your form needs to be in form view, and an invoice ID must be displayed in the form textbox for it to run correctly). If the data looks correct, name/save it.

```
SELECT [Invoice-Photo].[PhotoID], [Invoice-Photo].[Quantity], [Photo].[SalePrice] AS Cost
FROM [Invoice-Photo] INNER JOIN [Photo] ON [Invoice-Photo].[PhotoID] = [Photo].[ID]
WHERE [Invoice-Photo].[Invoice ID] = [Forms]![MyInvoiceFormName]![MyInvoiceTextboxName]
GROUP BY [Invoice-Photo].[PhotoID]
ORDER BY [Invoice-Photo].[PhotoID];
```

Then in design view of your form, drag the new query from the navigation pane into the area you want your subform to appear, it should create a subform out of your saved query automatically.

Now it should show you the related records for the Invoice ID shown in the main form. But it may not update when you choose a new customer or new invoice ID. To allow that to happen, you just need to add a `.requery` command to the `AfterUpdate` event of the control that you want to trigger the refresh of the subform. If you are comfortable with VBA, you can paste this code into the code builder for your `AfterUpdate` event:

```
[Forms]![MyInvoiceFormName]![MyNewSubformName].Requery
```

Now the subform should update after each selection change.